# I want to save textarea in Django with space characters

Tags: python, django

I want to save textarea in Django with space characters.

for example

I want to be saved like this

```
1. A  BC    D  E
 2. 1000  2000
```

The result is saved and viewed

```
1. A BC D E
2. 1000 2000
```

The source code above is my form.

```
class createPlanForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = plan_models.Plan
    fields = [
        "title_for_plan",
        "contents_for_plan",
    ]

    widgets = {
        "title_for_plan": forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "title"}),
        "contents_for_plan": forms.Textarea(attrs={"placeholder": "contents"}),
    }
```

The source code above is my plan model

```
class Plan(core_model.TimeStampModel):

STATUS_ENROLLMENT = "ENROLLMENT"
STATUS_CONFIRM = "CONFIRM"
STATUS_COMPLETE = "COMPLETE"
STATUS_FAIL = "FAIL"
STATUS_SUCCESS = "SUCCESS"

STATUS_LIST = (
    (STATUS_ENROLLMENT, "Enrollment"),
    (STATUS_CONFIRM, "Confirm"),
    (STATUS_COMPLETE, "Complete"),
    (STATUS_FAIL, "Fail"),
    (STATUS_SUCCESS, "Success"),
)

group = models.ForeignKey("groups.Group", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey("users.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

title_for_plan = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)
contents_for_plan = models.TextField(blank=True,)

title_for_result = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)
contents_for_result = models.TextField(blank=True,)

start_day = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
end_day = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

status = models.CharField(
    choices=STATUS_LIST,
    default=STATUS_ENROLLMENT,
    blank=False,
    null=False,
    max_length=20,
)

def __str__(self):
    plan_id = str(self.id).zfill(8)
    return f"PLAN_{plan_id}"

def get_group_id(self):
    return self.group.id
```

If you have any additional things you need to do in Django, please let me know.

I wish you could let me know if there is a way:)

Comment: Can you add models for ```Plan``` Model

Comment: absolutely! Plan model added Thank you!!